# How does H2O Wireless work with the iPhone without needing any unlock?

Tags: iphone, wifi, unlock

My friend purchased an iPhone 4 that cannot be unlocked so the store sold him a new cell phone service called H2O Wireless. You simply pop in the sim card and it works without needing any unlock or chip. Does anybody have a clue on how it works?

Comment: SIM locks often bind a phone to a mobile provider, so as long as it's the same company, you can switch cards. I'm guessing that's what happened here.

Answer (score 3):

H₂O doesn't provide a network of its own. Instead, it purchases bandwidth in bulk from a carrier, in this case AT&T, and provides prepaid service using the carriers network.

So your friends phone isn't unlocked, but works just fine on the carrier network that its locked to.

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know. If they're using the same towers at AT&T and provide a lower price and no contract, it seems like a killer deal.